# PHP Exec Screen + Java file doesn't work

Tags: java, php, exec

When I try to open a JAVA application (Minecraft) with PHP exec, (screen), the jar file gets executed, (htop), but it doesn't work generate the files. It's like it doesn't have permission, but all the files are owned by www-data + 777 perms, just incase. What could be the problem?

Here is the code itself:

```
shell_exec("screen -dmS mcsrv java -Xmx512M -jar spigot.jar -o true nogui")
```

Comment: What happens if you exec this screen command manually from the same folder by the same user php process runs under?

Comment: It does totally work.

Comment: what's in its system out when you connect to that screen?

Comment: You mean the screen output? Its like an infitite loop of the Jar trying to generate the files. Thats only what i see.

Comment: Yes, please share that. If it's to large, you can share a recurring exception and / or put that to external storage

Comment: Woah, it just decided to work, just started my VPS today, and it works somewhat. The problem is that it generates the files straight next to my php, even if the jar is located elsewhere.